# Pass data from one jsp to another and display that jsp view

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

Hey i am a php developer and this is my first go with jsp. Now i retrieved a Json string from my class and converted it into GSON. I display a field in my `result.jsp` for eg:- ID and on clicking the id it should go to `details.jsp` and show more info about that ID

Currently my result.jsp is as follows:-

```
<html>
<body>
     <div class="list-group">
                <% 
                   String json = (String)request.getAttribute("jsonstring");
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    ConCom diff = new ConCom();
                    diff = gson.fromJson(json, ConCom.class);
                    List<ComparisonResultDTOarr> ls = diff.getComparisonResultDTOarr();

                    for(int i = 0;i<ls.size();i++)
                    {
                        List<AuditItemLogsDTOArr> lsinner = ls.get(i).getAuditItemLogsDTOArr();
                        %><a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        <%out.println(lsinner.get(0).getKeyAsString());%></a><%
                    }
                    %>
                  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I read around SO and googled it and understood that that i could make a hidden form. Now I create a form with the following two fields and using the anchor tag i submit the form. But the values in the form need to be posted according to the ID clicked, how can i make that dynamic?

So if my form is as follows:-

```
<form action="details.jsp" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="phone">
</form>
```

And my details.jsp will be like:-

```
<%= request.getParameter("firstname") %>
<%= request.getParameter("phone") %>
```

I want the firstname and phone to be set according to the ID clicked and the form to be submitted. I can obtain the String/Integer value from my diff object in this page. Would i need to use JQuery? Any help?

Also i know i should be using JSTL. And i will get to that soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call a javascript function during the onclick event of your anchor tag:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="submitHiddenForm("<%=lsinner.getFirstName()%>", "<%=lsinner.getPhone()%>");">...
```

Your JS function would like like:

```
   function submitHiddenForm(firstName, phone) {

       document.getElementById("firstname").value = firstName;
       document.getElementById("phone").value = phone;
       // attach a name attribute to your form tag
       // submit the form
       document.myForm.submit();
   }
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** changed diff to lsinner, since that's the var used in the loop.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i'm looking for, just one more question. Suppose that some ID's have users with two phone numbers instead of 1, any suggestion on how to handle that?

Comment: Well for starters you should prepare an additional text field in your hidden form (id=phone2?) and handle it appropriately on the details.jsp. You can modify the submitHiddenForm javascript function and add another phone parameter. In the onclick call, just populate the slot for phone2 properly (if empty, give null or empty string). Again, you'll have to handle the different types of phone2 input on details.jsp :)

Comment: One last question, in my servlet i basically send the string to result.jsp, can i at the same time send it to details.jsp too? Like forward the view only to result but pass the response to both result and details?

Comment: Of course. As mentioned by @Lakshmi, you can add another hidden text field to the form: <input type="hidden" name="jsonString" id="jsonString" value="<%=json%>" />. When you submit this form to details.jsp, you can access the json string via: request.getParameter("jsonString");

Comment: So i implemented the above code, when i click on any of the ID's i don't know if the JS function is actually getting executed and also it isn't forwarding my view to details.jsp, do i need to add additional js for that?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could add an alert and also check the browser console (F12) for any errors.

Comment: The alert doesn't show up either which makes me think it is because the function is not being called. If i manage to fix this, when the function is called the form is submitted to details.jsp then the view will also change to details.jsp, am i right? And thank you for all the help!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Im curious as to why it's not being called. Did you notice any errors in the browser console?

Comment: There weren't any. When i do this <a href="#" onclick=
"alert('Are you sure you want to give us the deed to your house?')"></a> it shows the alert just won't show it in a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55906/discussion-between-damien-hawks-and-michael-sanchez).

Answer (score 1):

On click of the ID call a javascript function passing the  values inside the function you can dynamically set the values of the form by getting each element like `document.getElementById("firstname").value=value passed` similarly set the other fields and in the end `document.myform.submit();`

Note since we are fetching HTML elements by Id you can use

```
<form action="details.jsp" method="post" name="myform">
First name: <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="hidden" name="phone" id="phone">
</form>
```

`type="hidden"` will hide the elements.
check these for better understanding.

[How to submit a form using javascript?](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the diff object in details.jsp as well, it should be enough to pass only the ID as a parameter, in a normal link.

```
<a href="details.jsp?id=<%= id %>">details</a>
```

You'd probably do the same in PHP.

JQuery is client side JavaScript and not required to solve your problem.

Comment: No i don't have the diff object in details.jsp but thank you for the suggestion.